# FreqTable with random values(#C)

Tags: c#

I would like to make a frequency table with random numbers.
So i have created a array that generates 11 random values between 0 and 9999.

```
        public void FillArrayRandom(int[] T)
    {
        Random Rndint = new Random();

        for (int i=0; i < T.Length; i++)
        {
            T[i] = Rndint.Next(0, 9999);
        }
    }/*FillArrayRandom*/
```

The result i want is something alike this:(bar height up to 21) So this will be a constant.

```
                 *
        *        *
  *     *        *          (the highest value will have the largest row/bar)
  *     *    *   *
  0     1    2   3  .....(index value's)
931   6669  10 8899 .... (up to 11 random values)
```

My question is how do i exactly caculate the frequency between those 11 random values?
The bars should have a relative relation with each other depending on there frequency.
I would only like to use 1 single array in my program (for the generated values).

F = (F * 21?) / ...? Really no clue how to obtain the proper results.

If a frequency is >=21 write *   If a frequency is >=20 write *   If a frequency is >=19 write *  , and so on until i reach 1. (and the full table is displayed

Basicly i would like to  print the table line per line with consolewrite(line).

etc...

Regards.

Comment: Your question is confusing. A frequency table lists the number of times a number is added. If you have two times 931 the table will show 2 at position 931.

What do you mean with your frequency?

And how can it go to 21 if you only have 11 values?

Comment: Your code is a bit confusing too. It sounds like you need two arrays, one for the 11 random values and another to populate from those 11 rand values? First populating your rand source array and then your final array?

Answer (score 0):

To calculate frequency you could use a Dictionary defined something like:

```
freqDict Dictionary<int, int> = new Dictionary<int, int>();
```

Where the first integer (K) is the key that corresponds to your random value or its index in the values array, either way it has to be unique and able to reference to a particular value. The second integer is the value (V) that is your count of each key.

Next, walk your array of randomly generated values and if it's not represented in the dictionary add it with the new key and set the value to 1. If the dictionary already contains the key you simply increment the value by 1. Do this for each value in your rand array and you will have a dictionary with a frequency distribution.